# How to make Vaadin Spreadsheet read only

Tags: java, vaadin, spreadsheet

I would like to have Vaadin spreadsheet component in the view only mode. I have tried everything but I could not solve the problem( I still can edit the file).
I am using Vaadin 8.

Here are what I have tried so far:

1. Item 1

https://demo.vaadin.com/spreadsheet/ .I have looked at Report Mode. The code is:

```
if (resource != null) {
sampleFile = new File(resource.toURI());
spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet(sampleFile);
spreadsheet.setReportStyle(true);
spreadsheet.setActiveSheetProtected("");
spreadsheet.setRowColHeadingsVisible(false);
}
```

What I have written:

```
spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet(tempFile);
spreadsheet.setReportStyle(true);
spreadsheet.setActiveSheetProtected("");
```

Not working...

2. Item 2

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/10295629/vaadin-spreadsheet-readonly-mode

Not working...

3. Item 3

   ```
   spreadsheet.setActiveSheetProtected("ddd");   
   // OR    
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protectSheet("ddd");
   ```

   Not working...

What should I do to make spreadsheet read-only?

Comment: Have you tried to add `pointer-events: none;` to a spreadsheet via CSS? For example, to `v-spreadsheet` for testing purposes. It's not exactly as a read-only featrue, but might work as a workaround

Comment: Where is your `tempFile` coming from? Could it be, that you have faced this issue[Spreadsheet setActiveSheetProtected("") method not working as expected](https://github.com/vaadin/spreadsheet/issues/388)?

Comment: @anasmi the tempFile is coming from the hard drive. In some folder, not in Google drive, not in Dropbox. I will try to add `pointer-events: none;` and try that. I  will let you know whether it works or not